# What is the proper way to close a django dev project without deleting the database

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, django-3.0

python 3.8
docker
django 3

I have a django project that I just converted to docker. I've noticed that everytime that I spin down my docker container and then spin it back up, my database gets deleted.

When I spin the docker container down is it supposed to kill the database? If not, then something is wrong. If so, then what's the best practice to take django offline while I make changes w/o killing the database

command:
`docker-compose up -d --build`

output

```
Creating myproject_db_1 ... done
Creating myproject_web_1 ... done
```

command

`docker-compose down -v`

output

```
Stopping myproject_db_1 ... done
Stopping myproject_web_1 ... done
Removing myproject_db_1 ... done
Removing myproject_web_1 ... done
```

I do have an entry point script and it used to flush the db everytime, but I have commented that out now.
entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

#python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./src
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev.db
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```